# dplyr mutate throws "Error: invalid subscript type 'closure'" error

Tags: r, dplyr, sentimentr

I'm trying to use the sentiment_by in sentimentR with dplyr's mutate

This for example works: 
`content <- mutate(content, word_count = sentiment_by(story)$word_count)`

but

This for example works:
 `content.sd <- mutate(content, word_count = sentiment_by(story)$sd)`

gives the error Error: `invalid subscript type 'closure'`

but `sentiment_by(content$story[1])` works

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the `str()` of `sentiment_by(story)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following instead

`content <- mutate(content, stdev = sentiment_by(story)[["sd"]])`